# appending images with similar filename (1 char different)

Tags: jquery, arrays, append

I need to dynamically append to a div several images with similar filenames, ie. c-abc.01.jpg, c-abc.02.jpg, c-abc.03.jpg, etc.

I think I need to create an array using attr('src') and then append the array, but I'm not sure how to do this with src. I've got as far as it loads a single image and now I'm stuck beyond thinking that an array would help. However, [jquery array api](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) states:

> In addition, .attr() should not be used on plain objects, **arrays**, the window, or the document.

So now I'm really confused and would really appreciate some direction!

MTIA.

**My jquery:**

```
$('img.displayer').live('click', function (e) {

    var activeID = $(this).attr('id');
    if($('img.displayer').hasClass('current')) {
        $('img.displayer.current').removeClass('current');
    }
    $(this).addClass('current');
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#content-row').fadeOut(700, function() {
        $('#content-image').empty();
        $('#content-text').stop(true, true).load( 'all-text.html #' + activeID );
        $('#content-image').append('<img src="images/c-' + activeID + '.01.jpg" />');
    });
    $('#content-row').fadeIn(700);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you want to append images "c-abc-01.jpg" through c-abc-09.jpg".  You could do it like this using a for loop:

```
$('img.displayer').live('click', function (e) {

    var activeID = $(this).attr('id');
    if($('img.displayer').hasClass('current')) {
        $('img.displayer.current').removeClass('current');
    }
    $(this).addClass('current');
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#content-row').fadeOut(700, function() {
        $('#content-image').empty();
        $('#content-text').stop(true, true).load( 'all-text.html #' + activeID );
        for (var i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
            $('#content-image').append('<img src="images/c-' + activeID + '.0' + i + '.jpg" />');
    });
    $('#content-row').fadeIn(700);
});
```